# Why am I getting an error after successful deleteRecord in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I get this error after calling deleteRecord and then save on an entity. I'm using the DS.RESTAdapter and delete works perfectly well in the backend but the console is throwing this error

```
Error: No model was found for 'id'
at new Error (native)
at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:913:19)
at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9808:33)
at JSONSerializer.extend.extractSingle (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:3021:28)
at superWrapper [as extractSingle] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:1295:16)
at Ember.Object.extend.extractSave (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2511:21)
at Ember.Object.extend.extractDeleteRecord (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2468:21)
at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2368:37)
at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:10436:32
at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:10016:19) ember.js?body=1:3524
```

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: No model was found for 'id'

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        deletetag: function(params) {
            this.get('store').find('usertag', params.id).then(function(rec){
                rec.deleteRecord();
                rec.save();
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Why is ember trying to return a factory instance of a model called "id" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb mistake. The error was the json returned from the destroy method was missing the object root.