# Include root in django rest framework responses

Tags: json, django, rest, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I have a ready Django project that serves JSON via the rest_framework and its viewsets. Now I would like to write the client using Ember. Here is my setup:

- Django 1.6.5
- Ember 1.6.1
- Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
- jQuery 2.1.1

My Django server runs on the default port 8000 under localhost. I test my Ember application by opening `index.html` in the browser. Therefore, I customised the ApplicationAdapter like so

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8000',
});
```

I try to fetch a list of artists from `http://localhost:8000/artists`. The specified route is

```
App.ArtistsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.store.find('artists');
    }
});
```

And the response I get back from the server when I open the mentioned url in the browser is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kollegah",
        "origin": "Germany",
        "genre": "German Rap"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Peter Fox",
        "origin": "Germany",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Farid Bang",
        "origin": "Germany",
        "genre": "German Rap"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Eko Fresh",
        "origin": "Germany",
        "genre": "German Rap"
    }
]
```

When fetching the data I these two Ember errors:

-`Error while processing route: artists No model was found for 'artists' Error: No model was found for 'artists'`

-`No model was found for 'artists' Error: No model was found for 'artists'`

The problem is that I have specified a model already

```
var attr = DS.attr;
App.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr,
    origin: attr,
    genre: attr,
});
```

I suppose the problem is the missing root element at the beginning of each JSON response. I suggest it should look like this example from the [Ember Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/):

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "comments": ["1", "2"],
    "user" : "dhh"
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "Rails is unagi"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "Omakase O_o"
  }]
}
```

After searching a short while I found a similar problems with [Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444543/ember-js-error-no-model-was-found-for-id-while-saving-record-using-ember-data). I tried out the solution for Django mentioned in [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824807/adding-root-element-to-json-response-django-rest-framework) but I got the same errors.

Does anybody know a server-side solution for this problem? The [Ember Data Django Adapter](https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter) could be one for the client side. Unfortunately, it is designed as a node plugin and at the moment I don't use it for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The Ember Data Django Adapter is the most simple way of solving your problem, and if you pay attention to the docs, there are [instructions for using it without ember-cli](https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/wiki/Installation#vanilla-ember).